# Circular dependency with type aliases

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following code which contains type aliases made with the C++ `using` keyword, but the problem is that `object` depends on `value` which in turns depends on `object`. Since it's a type alias, there is (to my knowledge) no way to make a forward declaration of it.

```
#include <variant>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using integer = int64_t;

using flt = double;

using string = std::string;

using object = std::unordered_map<std::string, value>;

using value = std::variant<integer, flt, string, object>;
```

Is there a way to make a forward declaration of a type alias so that the following code compiles or any other way to achieve what I am attempting to do?

Comment: How would you declare it without `using`? How can you have an endless variant of unordered_map of variants of unordered_map of variants of unordered_map.... ?

Comment: @KamilCuk The size is not infinite, the map allocates elements dynamically.

Comment: @0x400921FB54442D18 The size of the object wouldn' be (if it were allowed), but the type name would be infinitely long.

Comment: Look at *recursive variant*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since it's a type alias, there is (to my knowledge) no way to make a forward declaration of it.

No, there is no way. There is nothing like a forward declaration of a type alias.

I think the closest you can get to is:

```
struct object;
struct value;

struct object
{
   std::unordered_map<std::string, value*> data;
};

struct value
{
   std::variant<integer, flt, string, object> data;
};
```

or

```
struct object;
struct value;

struct value
{
   std::variant<integer, flt, string, object*> data;
};

struct object
{
   std::unordered_map<std::string, value> data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> or any other way to achieve what I am attempting to do?

Well, you could use `std::any`:

```
using object = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any>;

using value = std::variant<integer, flt, string, object>;
```

although it will make your code mode difficult.

Comment: @0x400921FB54442D18 no argument here. It's just ... I don't know what you are trying to do. The design seems overly complicated.

Comment: How would you represent a data format, such as JSON, in terms of C++ structures?

Comment: @0x400921FB54442D18 take inspiration from how others do it: https://github.com/nlohmann/json